# get the id of selected category php

Tags: php

```
<a href="report_product.php?id=<?php echo  $data['category']; ?>">
```

this line shows the name of category for example stationary..but this should be the id of selected category.is there any need to declare the `id?$category_id = $_POST['category_id'];` like this?
i tried with this also but it gives an error of `undefined index`. through this link i want to show the list of products on another page associated with selected category
i am on the learning phase and stuck on this issue kindly help me to sort out that

```
if(isset($_POST['search_category'])){ 
      // $category_id = $_POST['category_id'];   
      $records = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT DISTINCT category , 
      (SELECT COUNT(products.name) FROM products where category_id=categories.id) AS total_products,
      ( 
          SELECT SUM(quantity)  FROM productstock a
          LEFT JOIN products b ON a.product_id=b.id
          LEFT JOIN categories c ON b.category_id=c.id
          where c.deleted=0   AND b.category_id = categories.id
          GROUP BY category_id
      ) AS available_stock, 
      SUM(product_qty*orignalCost) AS SaleWise_cost,
      SUM(product_qty*saleprice) AS SaleWise_price,
      SUM(product_qty*saleprice) AS total_sale , 
      SUM((product_qty*saleprice)-(product_qty*orignalCost)) AS profit
               FROM categories
               INNER JOIN products ON  categories.id =  products.category_id
               INNER JOIN sales ON  sales.product_id = products.id
               INNER JOIN productstock ON  productstock.product_id = products.id
               WHERE categories.deleted=0
               GROUP BY category_id;"); // fetch data from database
      while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records)) 
      {    
  ?>   
    <td><a href="report_product.php?id=<?php echo  $data['category']; ?>"><?php echo $data['category']; ?></a></td>   
    <td><?php echo $data['total_products']; ?></td>   
    <td><?php echo $data['available_stock']; ?></td>   
    <td><?php echo $data['SaleWise_cost']; ?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $data['SaleWise_price']; ?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $data['total_sale']; ?></td>  
    <td><?php echo $data['profit']; ?></td>  
    </tr> 
    <?php
      } }
    ?>
   </table>
```

Comment: As long as you can uniquely identify the category, it is both ok to use name or ID if you do not care about performance

Comment: but by getting this id i have to put WHERE condition on the next page query to fetch the data against this specific id

Comment: The hyperlink to `report_product.php` is sending the `$category_id` set to the URL parameter as `id`. In the other report script that will be in the `$_GET` super global array as `$_GET['id']`. If you hover the link, the browser will show the `id=1234`, or whatever the I'd may be in the hyperlink's text.

Comment: if(isset($_GET['id'])) have set the hyperlink as id....but it shows all the product list .I have to put where condition on query but on which base  put the WHERE condition...like WHERE category_id=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not selecting the category ID in you query add the ID column to the SELECT list.

For example, instead of

```
SELECT DISTINCT category, ...
```

Try doing

```
SELECT DISTINCT category, id ...
```

and then the ID should be returned in the data for use like...

```php
<a href="report_product.php?id=<?php echo $data['id']; ?>"><?php echo $data['category']; ?></a>
```

Comment: then what i will put in where condition to take only those products which belong to that category

Comment: <?php 
        if(isset($_GET['id'])){   
         $records = mysqli_query($db,"SELECT DISTINCT name , category_id, product_qty AS SKU, product_qty*orignalCost AS salewise_cost, product_qty*saleprice AS salewise_price,product_qty*saleprice AS total_sale,  ((product_qty*saleprice)-(product_qty*orignalCost)) AS profit
          FROM products 
          INNER JOIN categories ON products.category_id =categories.id 
          INNER JOIN sales ON  sales.product_id = products.id    ;"); 
    while($data = mysqli_fetch_array($records)){          
      ?>